# Change file upload size units from bytes to kilobytes?

Tags: config-overrides

A client has a request that the file size units in upload preferences be changed to a more familiar unit of KB (Kilobytes). It does make sense to me as well, as most operating systems display the file size as the same.

Is this configurable?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where the file size you'd like changed is displayed?

Comment: No, i don't think that the units for EE upload-preferences are configurable. Do you change it that often?

Comment: @GDmac I don't change it personally. But I have a client that adds new upload directories periodically and asked if I could change it.

Comment: You could make an accessory and use Jquery to "enhance" the field :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that's possible either.. ? I always just let Google figure it out for me; [Google Math](http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&sclient=psy-ab&q=700+kb+to+bytes&oq=700+kb+to+bytes&gs_l=hp.3...6831.10272.1.10357.15.12.0.2.2.0.142.689.9j2.11.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.zDunhEW7NEM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.d2k&fp=c2fad194df1bc4c6&biw=1463&bih=876). It's an extra step but manageable I think.